# How much CO2 would Starship 2.0 produce?

Tags: spacex, co2-deposit

In [a video redacted because why link to a hoax from SE] they  show Starship 2.0. It can carry up to 1000 tons into LEO. If this nonexistent spaceship were ever to be theoretical built, how much CO2 would it produce.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a hoax, there is no information on which to base an answer.

Comment: Even though it is a hoax, they do mention the size and also the number of engines it would theoretically have. I think it is possible to get some kind of number.

Comment: So do sci-fi books, and those would be off-topic too.

Answer (score 6):

The vehicle in the video is obviously impossible, obviously fake, and obviously fictional, and was photoshopped together for the sole reason of baiting gullible YouTube visitors into clicking on the video in order to generate some advertising money.

Since the vehicle does not exist, will never exist, and can never exist, it will obviously also never generate any CO<sub>2</sub>.

Comment: Internet fantasies about Starship 2.0 will generate CO2 too. A youtube video much more CO2 than some sentences of text only.

Comment: I changed the question a bit since it is clear that Starship 2.0 is fake.